# ¿Porque me indica un error al usar laravel excel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

quisiera usar laravel excel , en el cuál instale el paquete y produje de forma manual el provider y su alias , quisiera hacer uso de esta , pero me indica que está indefinido cuando la llamo , porque sucede esto y como podría solucionarlo? de antemano muchas gracias:

Codigo:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

class ExampleExport implements FromCollection
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

> Me indica el siguiente error : Undefined type
> 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection'.intelephense(1009)

Y en mi controlador :

```php
  public function export() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new ExampleExport, 'example.xlsx');
    }
```

Me indica que hay un error en "Excel" indicandome:

> Undefined type 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel'.intelephense(1009)

Implemente en la cabecera del controlador :

> use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

Y también como dije anteriormente agregue el alias y el provider en config/app.php

Imagenes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Verificaste si están bien las rutas? De seguro no estás accediendo bien a la ruta de la carpeta y por eso no está encontrando esas clases

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Hola! , Al parecer se soluciono, creo que era un problema de Visual Studio Code, lo reinicie y me tomo las clases correctamente!

Comment: me alegro que se haya solucionado, saludos.